# How to use a macro from one crate in another?

Tags: macros, rust, rust-crates

I'm struggling to make macros from my rust lib available to other rust projects.

Here's an example of how I'm trying to get this work at the moment.

**`lib.rs`**:

```
#![crate_name = "dsp"]
#![feature(macro_rules, phase)]
#![phase(syntax)]

pub mod macros;
```

**`macros.rs`**:

```
#![macro_escape]

#[macro_export]
macro_rules! macro(...)
```

**`other_project.rs`**:

```
#![feature(phase, macro_rules)]
#![phase(syntax, plugin, link)] extern crate dsp;

macro!(...) // error: macro undefined: 'macro!'
```

Am I on the right track? I've been trying to use std::macros as a reference, but I don't seem to be having much luck. Is there anything obvious that I'm missing?

Comment: Are you actually looking at doing digital signal processing industry or DSP stood for something else here?

Comment: @errordeveloper Yep! For audio specifically. It's still very early stages and quite bare bones, but I've got a callback (using portaudio) and the basis of a 'DSP' node framework ready. You can [check it out here](https://github.com/PistonDevelopers/rust-dsp) as a part of the Piston project. I'm currently using it in a generative music engine - I'm hoping to contribute some of the oscillator/synth work i've made very soon. Also, we're always open to contributions/help :-)

Comment: Sounds great! I'll check it out :) Feel free to drop a message to me @gmail.com. I was quite interested about how one can take advantage of NEON and VFP with Rust...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your attributes are tangled.

`#![…]` refers to the *outer* scope, while `#[…]` refers to the *next* item.

Here are some things of note:

1. In `lib.rs`, the `#![feature(phase)]` is unnecessary, and the `#![phase(syntax)]` is meaningless.
2. In `other_project.rs`, your `phase` attribute is applied to the *crate*, not to the `extern crate dsp;` item—this is why it does not load any macros from it. Remove the `!`.

Comment: Just because I've spent a lot of time to figure it out, and you may come here with the same problem: put both annotations either in `main.rs` or, when you define crate, in `lib.rs`, *not* in the file which you actually want to use macros in.

Comment: To have effect, `#![feature]` must be on the crate, which means the crate root file, which defaults to `lib.rs` or `main.rs`, as appropriate.